# Setting pagination

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

controllers/home.php

```
$this->page_model->counter($this->data['post_detail']->post_ID);
        $this->data['post_list'] = $this->post_model->post($this->data['post_detail']->post_ID);
        $this->data['gallery_list'] = $this->post_model->post($this->data['post_detail']->post_ID, true);       





        $isAjax = array('news-post');
        if (in_array($this->data['post_detail']->template_name, $isAjax))
        {
            if ( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request())
                redirect($this->data['page_detail']->post_alias);

            return $this->load->view($this->data['post_detail']->template_name, $this->data);
        }
        $this->load->view($this->data['post_detail']->template_name, $this->data);
```

views/news.php

```
<?php 
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://gsa-constructionspecialist.com/articles/article';
        $config['total_rows'] = 14;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        ?>

    <div class="w626 content right">
        <?php
        if ($post_list){
        foreach ($post_list as $pl){
        ?>
        <div>
            <p><br><br><strong><?php echo $pl->post_title; ?></strong></p>
            <p><?php echo date('F jS, Y',strtotime($pl->post_date)); ?></p>
            <br/>
            <div style="text-align:justify"><?php echo word_limiter(strip_tags($pl->post_content),25); ?><a href="<?php echo site_url('articles/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/detail/'.$pl->post_alias); ?>"><span style="color:#fff">&nbsp;&nbsp;Read More ></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <?php } } ?>

    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();   ?>
```

I am trying to set the pagination but it only appears on the bottom and it does not hide the articles that suppose to be on the next page.

Please help fix the codes?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The pagination class will generate pages numbers based on the information you provide to it, however its up to you to generate the actual results for a particular page. You might tell the pagination class it's 5 results per page, but in reality it doesn't know whether you're outputting 5 results per page or 500.

It seems to me as though:

```
$this->data['post_list'] = $this->post_model->post($this->data['post_detail']->post_ID);
```

needs the current page number passing in, i.e.

```
$this->data['post_list'] = $this->post_model->post($this->data['post_detail']->post_ID, $current_page);
```

You then need to modify your database query within the model using LIMIT to limit the number of results (and the offset) for that page.

Does this help?